# Objective-C: Completing an interval timer

Tags: objective-c, audio, timer

I'm currently developing an interval timer, which might make you think of the Gymboss timer. This is where the comparison ends.

Let's imagine that you set your whole workout to 10 minutes with a stepper. You want each repetition to last 1 minute and each break, 30 seconds. While I managed to code the sound that will play at the end of the workout in the "chrono" method, I'm still struggling to make the sound play when a repetition or a break ends. This is the the header's relevant part of the code:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface AutoLayoutViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
// 1. The three green labels
// Workout's timer
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *workoutTimer;
    NSTimer *workoutCountdown;
}

// Repetition's length
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *repetitionLabel;

// Break's length
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *breakLabel;




// 2. The three steppers

// Stepper for Workout's total length
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStepper *secondsWorkoutChanged;

// Stepper for Repetition's length
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStepper *secondsRepetitionChanged;

// Stepper for Break's length
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStepper *secondsBreakChanged;



// 4. The start button
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *startPauseButton;    

@end
```

Secondly, this is the relevant part of the implementation file:

```
// 1. Steppers

// Stepper for Workout's length
- (IBAction)secondsWorkoutChanged:(UIStepper *)sender {

    /* User increases value of seconds with stepper. Whenever variable for seconds is equal or greater than 60, the program sets the value of minutes through this division: seconds / 60. */
    seconds = [sender value];
    minutes = seconds / 60;


    /* "If" statement for resetting seconds to 0 in order for the label to look like a watch. REAL number of seconds stored by stepper modulus operated by 60.
     */
    if (seconds > 59) {
        seconds = seconds % 60;
    } // End if.


    [workoutTimer setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2i : %2i", (int) minutes, (int) seconds]];

}

// Stepper for Repetition's length
- (IBAction)secondsRepetitionChanged:(UIStepper *)sender {

    /* User increase value of secondsBreak with stepper. Whenever variable for secondsBreak exceeds 60, the program sets the value of minutesBreak by dividing the number of seconds with 60. */
    secondsRepetition = [sender value];
    minutesRepetition = secondsRepetition / 60;


    /* "If" statement for resetting secondsBreak to 0 in order for the label to look like a watch. REAL number of seconds stored by stepper modulus operated by 60.
     */
    if (secondsRepetition > 59) {

        secondsRepetition = secondsRepetition % 60;
    } // End if.



    [_repetitionLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2i : %2i", (int) minutesRepetition, (int) secondsRepetition]];
}



// Stepper for Break's length
- (IBAction)secondsBreakChanged:(UIStepper *)sender {

    /* User increase value of secondsBreak with stepper. Whenever variable for secondsBreak exceeds 60, the program sets the value of minutesBreak by dividing the number of seconds with 60. */
    secondsBreak = [sender value];
    minutesBreak = secondsBreak / 60;



    /* "If" statement for resetting secondsBreak to 0 in order for the label to look like a watch. REAL number of seconds stored by stepper modulus operated by 60.
     */
    if (secondsBreak > 59) {
        secondsBreak = secondsBreak % 60;
    } // End if.



    [_breakLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2i : %2i", (int) minutesBreak, (int) secondsBreak]];
}




// 3. The buttons

// Method for countdown

- (void)chrono:(NSTimer *)timer
{ // First brace for "chrono" method.

    // Timer loses 1 second when started.
    seconds = seconds -= 1;

    workoutTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%2i : %2i", minutes, seconds];

    // If "statement for including minutes in countdown.
   if (seconds <= 0) {
       if (minutes <= 0) {
           [workoutCountdown invalidate]; // 1: If both minutes and seconds = 0, countdown ends.


           // 1.1: Alarm for end of workout.
           CFBundleRef workoutEnded = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
           CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
           soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(workoutEnded, (CFStringRef) @"alarm_clock_ringing", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);

           UInt32 soundID;
           AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
           AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);


           // Reset all steppers when workout ends.
           _secondsWorkoutChanged.value = 0;

           _secondsRepetitionChanged.value = 0;

           _secondsBreakChanged.value = 0;


           // Reset the text displayed in the label to zero.
           [workoutTimer setText:@"00 : 00"];

           [_repetitionLabel setText:@"00 : 00"];

           [_breakLabel setText:@"00 : 00"];


       } // End of "if" statement" for minutes.

       else { // Timer still running
           seconds = 60;
           minutes -= 1;

       } // End of else.

    } // End of all the "if" (general).


} // Last brace for "chrono" method.



 //Start button
-(IBAction) startPauseButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    workoutCountdown = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(chrono:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

My question will be as follows. How do I make a sound play when a repetition and a break end? For the purpose of the demonstration, you may use the line of code for the sound from the "chrono" method.

Thanks.

Anh Khoi

Comment: Hi. could you please clarify on the terms _repitition_ and _break_ ? Should all the timers start exactly at the same time ? If possible, provide a workflow of the timers with an example.

Comment: Let's pretend that an user is doing sit-ups. His whole workout is 10 minutes. One minute after he's pressed the "Start" button, he'll hear a first alarm (repetition) telling him/her to stop his set of sit-ups. Thirty seconds following the first alarm, he/she will hear another one telling him/her that the break is over. 

Afterwards, both alarms will follow each other in a cycle until the workout is over. I am sure that I have to set a loop within the "chrono" method for that to happen.

Comment: This is what I have understood so far.
The repetition alarm determines how long you workout in one continuous stretch or set.
The break alarm sets the break time.
The total workout timer pauses when the repetition timer reaches a countdown of zero.
At this point, the repetition alarm gets reset to its original value and the break timer starts.
When the break timer reaches zero, the workout timer and the repetition timer starts its next cycle. Am I right so far ?

Comment: During the workout, the "Total workout timer" will keep running unless the user presses on the "pause" button. As for the other two components, when the repetition timer reaches zero, the alarm gets reset to its original value and the break timer starts. When the break timer reaches zero, the repetition timer and the one for the break enter the next cycle. So far, that's the whole picture of my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement the following changes in your *implementation* file:
[ **Note**: I have repositioned the declaration statements of the variables, and added two new *variables* `secondsValue` and `minutesValue`]

```
@implementation CDTViewController
{
    // instance variables
    int seconds;
    int minutes;
    int secondsRepetition;
    int minutesRepetition;
    int secondsBreak;
    int minutesBreak;
    int secondsValue;
    int minutesValue;
    BOOL startBreakTimer;
    BOOL startRepetitionTimer;
}
```

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    startRepetitionTimer = YES;
    startBreakTimer = NO;
}
```

```
- (IBAction)secondsRepetitionChanged:(UIStepper *)sender {

    minutesRepetition = [sender value] / 60;
    secondsRepetition = (int)[sender value] % 60;
    secondsValue = secondsRepetition;
    minutesValue = minutesRepetition;
    [_repetitionLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2i : %2i", (int) minutesRepetition, (int) secondsRepetition]];
}
```

```
- (IBAction)secondsBreakChanged:(UIStepper *)sender {

    minutesBreak = [sender value] / 60;
    secondsBreak = (int)[sender value] % 60;
    [_breakLabel setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2i : %2i", (int) minutesBreak, (int) secondsBreak]];
}
```

```
- (void)chrono:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    seconds -= 1;
    secondsValue -= 1;

    if (seconds < 0) {
        seconds = 59;
        minutes -= 1;
        if (minutes < 0) {
            minutes = 0;
        }
    }

    if (secondsValue < 0) {
        secondsValue = 59;
        minutesValue -= 1;
        if (minutesValue < 0) {
            minutesValue = 0;
        }
    }

    workoutTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%2i : %2i", minutes, seconds];

    if (startRepetitionTimer) {
        _repetitionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%2i : %2i",minutesValue, secondsValue];
        _breakLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%2i : %2i", minutesBreak, secondsBreak];
        if (secondsValue == 0) {
            if (minutesValue == 0) {
                startBreakTimer = YES;
                startRepetitionTimer = NO;
                secondsValue = secondsBreak;
                minutesValue = minutesBreak;

                /* write code to play repetition alarm
             here */
            }
        }
    }
    else if (startBreakTimer) {
        _repetitionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%2i : %2i",minutesRepetition, secondsRepetition];
        _breakLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%2i : %2i", minutesValue, secondsValue];
        if (secondsValue == 0) {
            if (minutesValue == 0) {
                startBreakTimer = NO;
                startRepetitionTimer = YES;
                secondsValue = secondsRepetition;
                minutesValue = minutesRepetition;

                /* write code to play break alarm
             here */
            }
        }
    }

    if (seconds == 0) {
        if (minutes == 0) {
            [workoutCountdown invalidate];

            // Alarm for end of workout.

            // Reset all steppers when workout ends.
            _secondsWorkoutChanged.value = 0;
            _secondsRepetitionChanged.value = 0;
            _secondsBreakChanged.value = 0;

            // Reset the text displayed in the label to zero.
            [workoutTimer setText:@"00 : 00"];
            [_repetitionLabel setText:@"00 : 00"];
            [_breakLabel setText:@"00 : 00"];
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this logic helps you !

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! I tested the logic you described in the iOS simulator and it works.